# How to console.log Moment.js version?

Tags: momentjs

Is there a way to find out what version of **Moment.js** is being used?
[Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Simply use `moment.version`. It seems that this property is not mentioned in the docs page, but it is quite easy to get it looking at library [code on github](https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/2.18.1/moment.js#L4429).

Here a live example:

```js
console.log(moment.version)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```