# How to get the timezone version used by moment-timezone?

Tags: node.js, momentjs, moment-timezone

I am using `moment-timezone` for working with timezones in `Node.js`. I am wondering if there is a way to get the current timezone (file) version being used. For example, the latest IANA version at the time of writing this is `2021a`.

I need to know this, so that I can update dateTimes in my database whenever a new version is released.

I read through all of the documentation, but I couldn't find it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `moment.tz.dataVersion`. It seems that this property is not mentioned in the docs page, but it is quite easy to get it looking at library [code on github](https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/blob/0.5.33/moment-timezone.js#L574).

```js
// Get momentjs version
console.log(moment.version);
// Get moment timezone version
console.log(moment.tz.version);
// Get data used
console.log(moment.tz.dataVersion);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.33/moment-timezone-with-data-2012-2022.min.js"></script>
```

This is similar to: [How to console.log Moment.js version?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45961818/4131048).

Comment: Thank you so much @VincenzoC! That is exactly what I was looking for :)